# RESTful API response status code disambiguation

Tags: web-services, http, rest, response, http-status-codes

I'm developing a RESTful API and have a question about the most appropriate response status codes for certain scenarios.

Consider the case where the client makes a GET request for a resource. How can I disambiguate a "not found" response for the case where the resource legitimately does not exist, vs. the case where there may be a minor service interruption (during deployment, etc).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The W3C defines [very specific status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for nearly all cases you can think of. For your specific needs:

- Not Found: 404
- Service Unavailable: 503

Answer (score 6):

Send a 404 status code for "Not found"

Send some [500-series error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) for error conditions on the server-side.